# Viewing question record

Tags: support

In order to earn the "Curious" badge you need to ask a well received question on 5 separate days and maintain a positive question record. I have a question record of 0.9 and 21 days in which I have asked well received questions. Why am I not eligible for this badge?

Comment: I edited my question with the data relevant for me. I don't think I have deleted questions at least not that many.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Your profile indicates that you don't have a positive question record.

[image]

What that actually *means* is described in [Meta's Badge FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/67399/175248).

> - Any open question that is not deleted and has a of score >= 1 is considered well-received
> - Only days where *all* questions asked have been well-received, count
> - A positive question record means you don't have too many closed, downvoted or deleted questions, overall. The formula is (total
>     questions - negative questions - closed - deleted)/total questions >=
>     0.5. **Questions that have been downvoted and closed and deleted count three times in this calculation!**

Emphasis mine on the last part.

If you've got any deleted or closed questions, then they're counting for triple, thus pushing your percentage lower.

---

Let's walk through a bit of math.

- You have 32 questions **total**.
- You have **22 questions which are well-received** (score >= 1).
- The only days that count are days in which **all questions** you've asked are well-received.  This disqualifies:

  - 16 February 2015
  - 9 January 2014

  ...for a total of **20 eligible days**.
- You have 1 question which is downvoted below 0, so that counts triple
- You have 2 questions which are closed, which *includes* the downvoted question.  These count triple against you.

Since we don't know the deleted questions you have, that puts your score at:

```
(20 - 3 - 6 - x) / 32 ~ 11x/32
```

[Solving for x such that `11x/32  0.5`](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+x%2C++%2820+-+3+-+6+-+x%29+%2F+32+%3E%3D+0.5), we arrive at `x <= -5`.

This means you have around 2 deleted questions which are interfering with you getting this badge.

I could be wrong; I'm treating the first expression of "total questions" as "total eligible questions", because otherwise the calculation looked to be entirely too simple.  But, this is the rough math.

Comment: Thanks, I checked my question list and there are 32 question of which one was downvoted and deleted and one was downvoted and closed. The script at http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/202517/asking-record says I have a 0.9 question record. So I still am not sure what the problem is.

Comment: Let's start with the fact that SEDE [doesn't consider deleted content](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/237428/175248) in its queries...

Comment: @BenjyKessler:  I've added a bit of math to the answer here.  The SEDE query doesn't take into account eligible questions (it seems to be using the same math as described in the badge description), but there are only so many eligible days that a user has a good question.

Comment: Strictly speaking, I think it's only dv + cv + delv questions that get the full triple whammy; questions that got downvoted and closed without being deleted would only get double, and questions that only got downvoted, or only closed, only get a single count. The corrected query appears to be http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+x%2C++%2820+-+1+-+4+-+x%29+%2F+%2832%2Bx%29+%3C%3D+0.5

Comment: Well, actually the calculation should be http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+x%2C++%2821+-+1+-+4+-+3x%29+%2F+%2832%2Bx%29+%3C+0.5. Any one deleted question would suffice.

Comment: so a question with negative votes would only count as 1 against you? or does it count as 3 against you if the question has -3 votes?

Comment: @ACE:  If the question only has a negative score then it counts once.  If it's got a negative score and it's closed, it counts twice.