# Does a previous question ban prohibit gaining certain badges in the future?

Tags: discussion, bug

Earlier on in my time on Stack Overflow I was unfortunate enough to be handed a question ban, I came out of that ban a while ago and have asked some well received questions since then, hitting the criteria for the [curious badge](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/4127/curious) but I have not been given the badge, I have definitely had more than 5 since coming out of the ban, does the ban prohibit me from ever getting the curious and the inquisitive badges? If I can never get this badge it makes no sense for it to be my recommended badge.

Here is a picture of the my badge progress for curious.

[image: badge process]

Comment: It seems very unlikely that a ban would directly affect this - a ban is supposed to be just a ban, ideally (like in your case) temporary. But perhaps you have deleted negatively-rated questions that do?

Comment: @Pekka웃 i believe i have not had any negative questions since the ban was lifted

Comment: My crystal ball says that you deleted some downvoted questions.  Users have a strong knack for wiping them from memory.  There is a checkbox in your profile, but it only shows recent deletions.

Comment: @HansPassant can you see when they were?

Comment: No, only a moderator can see them.  And you.

Comment: no deleted recent, how do i see the older ones?

Comment: There may be no way to do so - in which case you could be effectively barred from getting that specific badge.

Comment: @Pekka웃, why would they be barred? If they keep asking questions, and keep the positive streak, they will eventually reach a positive record, won't they?

Comment: @yivi that depends on what "positive question record" means exactly. I interpreted it as *only* questions with a net vote count of zero or more.

Comment: @Pekka웃, the actual formula is: `total questions - negative questions - closed - deleted) / total questions >= 0.5`. [Source](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions/67399#67399), linked in a comment to the answer below.

Comment: Update. I just got the badge

Answer (score 4):

You can always recover from a question ban. Getting blocked means you have a negative record, but then getting unblocked afterward, and remaining in the green without getting blocked again, is a good sign. I'd be surprised if you didn't eventually attain this badge provided you continue asking good questions.

Comment: would i not have recieved the badge by now though?

Comment: @WhatsThePoint: Oh... good question. Call me surprised, then.

Answer (score 2):

It could possible be that you don't have a positive question record, you can check if you select to track that badge and then click on it, it will expand this popup
 [image: badge popup]

And you'll either have a tick or a cross

Comment: does the previous ban keep me in a negative record though?

Comment: By now your question kinda morphed to "how do I achieve a positive question record, and how does a previous ban affect the calculation, if it does?".

Comment: @WhatsThePoint I don't think so, I used [this query](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/202517/asking-record?UseIds=7147233) and it comes out as `0.7` although it doesn't take into account any deleted questions you have, I got the query from https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291457/viewing-question-record which could also make this question a duplicate.